# How to use JavaScript functions on HTML data loaded through jQuery.append() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using JSON data and using it to create HTML data that represents Question and MCQ. I have been able to load the data in HTML but now I want to capture the response of user in an array. I want to store which radio button user has checked after User presses the submit button.

```js
var obj = JSON.parse(
  '{"single": [{"id": 1,"question": "this is a question1?","option": ["option1","option2","option3","option4"]},{"id": 2,"question": "this is a question2?","option": ["option1","option2","option3","option4"]},{"id": 3,"question": "this is a question3?","option": ["option1","option2","option3","option4"]},{"id": 4,"question": "this is a question4?","option": ["optionu1","optionu2","optionu3","optionu4"]}],"multiple": [{"id": 1,"question": "this is a multiple question1?","option": ["optionm1","option2lj","option3","option4"]},{"id": 2,"question": "this is a multiple question2?","option": ["optionm1","option2j","option3","option4"]},{"id": 3,"question": "this is a multiple question3?","option": ["optionm1","option2gg","option3","option4"]},{"id": 4,"question": "this is a multiple question4?","option": ["optionm1","option2h","option3","option4"]}],"integer": [{"id": 1,"question": "this is a int question1?"},{"id": 2,"question": "this is a int question2?"},{"id": 3,"question": "this is a int question3?"},{"id": 4,"question": "this is a int question4?"}]}'
);
var s = [0, 0]; //only single correct;
var t = []; //only multiple choice
var u = []; //only numeric type
$(document).ready(function() {
});
function my(check, sub, err) {
  console.log(check + " " + sub + " " + err);
  var f = 0;
   if (document.getElementById("test" + check - 3).checked) {
    f = 1;
    s[0] = 1;
  } else if (document.getElementById("test" + check - 2).checked) {
    f = 1;
    s[0] = 2;
  } else if (document.getElementById("test" + check - 1).checked) {
    f = 1;
    s[0] = 3;
  } else if (document.getElementById("test" + check).checked) {
    f = 1;
    s[0] = 4;
  } else {
    $("#error" + err).show();
  }
  if(f===1){  
    document.getElementById("submit" + sub).disabled = true;
    $("#error"+err)
      .show()
      .text("Your answer has been successfully submitted.");
  }
}

function read() {
  var pages = obj.single;
  var x = 4; //for tests and creating new ID's
  var sub = 1; //for submission
  var err = 1; //for errors
  pages.forEach(function(page) {
    var test =
      "<div class='row'>" +
      "<div class='col s12 m12'>" +
      "<div class='card teal accent-1 hoverable' id='car'>" +
      "<div class='card-content  center-align'>" +
      "<span class='card-title'>" +
      "Question " +
      page.id +
      "</span>" +
      "<form action='#'>" +
      "<p>" +
      page.question +
      "</p>" +
      "<p><input name='group1' type='radio' id='test" +
      (x - 3) +
      "'/>" +
      "<label for='test" +
      (x - 3) +
      "'>" +
      page.option[0] +
      "</label></p>" +
      "<p><input name='group1' type='radio' id='test" +
      (x - 2) +
      "'/>" +
      "<label for='test" +
      (x - 2) +
      "'>" +
      page.option[1] +
      "</label></p>" +
      "<p><input name='group1' type='radio' id='test" +
      (x - 1) +
      "'/>" +
      "<label for='test" +
      (x - 1) +
      "'>" +
      page.option[2] +
      "</label></p>" +
      "<p><input name='group1' type='radio' id='test" +
      x +
      "'/>" +
      "<label for='test" +
      x +
      "'>" +
      page.option[3] +
      "</label></p>" +
      "</form>" +
      "<h6 id='error" +
      err +
      "'>Please select an option</h6>" +
      "</div>" +
      "<div class='card-action center'>" +
      "<button class='btn'  onclick='my(" +
      x +
      "," +
      sub +
      "," +
      err +
      ")' id='submit" +
      sub +
      "'>Submit</button>" +
      "</div>" +
      "</div>" +
      "</div>" +
      "</div>";
    $(".container").append(test);
    console.log(test);
    x += 4;
    sub++;
    err++;
  });
}
read();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

I am also Using materialize.css in my Code.
My problem is after clicking the submit function nothing works.That is it goes into the function but doesn't checks if user has checked a radio button(I figured that it doesn't allows any jquery method to work.)
But If I place my function in $(document).ready() method my function doesn't work but any single jQuery event placed in it will work.I am really confused please help me.
Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Where is `.container` in your HTML?

Comment: This looks overly complicated. See how to bind events to dynamic elements here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: I just added the .container method,Please check again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an operator precedence problem. Addition and subtraction are left associative, so `"test" + check - 3` is first does `"test" + check` and then subtracts `3` from that. But `"test4" - 3` makes no sense, you can't subtract a number from a string. You need parentheses to override the default, `"test" + (check -3)` so it does the subtraction first and then concatenates the result.

```js
var obj = JSON.parse(
  '{"single": [{"id": 1,"question": "this is a question1?","option": ["option1","option2","option3","option4"]},{"id": 2,"question": "this is a question2?","option": ["option1","option2","option3","option4"]},{"id": 3,"question": "this is a question3?","option": ["option1","option2","option3","option4"]},{"id": 4,"question": "this is a question4?","option": ["optionu1","optionu2","optionu3","optionu4"]}],"multiple": [{"id": 1,"question": "this is a multiple question1?","option": ["optionm1","option2lj","option3","option4"]},{"id": 2,"question": "this is a multiple question2?","option": ["optionm1","option2j","option3","option4"]},{"id": 3,"question": "this is a multiple question3?","option": ["optionm1","option2gg","option3","option4"]},{"id": 4,"question": "this is a multiple question4?","option": ["optionm1","option2h","option3","option4"]}],"integer": [{"id": 1,"question": "this is a int question1?"},{"id": 2,"question": "this is a int question2?"},{"id": 3,"question": "this is a int question3?"},{"id": 4,"question": "this is a int question4?"}]}'
);
var s = [0, 0]; //only single correct;
var t = []; //only multiple choice
var u = []; //only numeric type
$(document).ready(function() {
});
function my(check, sub, err) {
  console.log(check + " " + sub + " " + err);
  var f = 0;
   if (document.getElementById("test" + (check - 3)).checked) {
    f = 1;
    s[0] = 1;
  } else if (document.getElementById("test" + (check - 2)).checked) {
    f = 1;
    s[0] = 2;
  } else if (document.getElementById("test" + (check - 1)).checked) {
    f = 1;
    s[0] = 3;
  } else if (document.getElementById("test" + check).checked) {
    f = 1;
    s[0] = 4;
  } else {
    $("#error" + err).show();
  }
  if(f===1){  
    document.getElementById("submit" + sub).disabled = true;
    $("#error"+err)
      .show()
      .text("Your answer has been successfully submitted.");
  }
}

function read() {
  var pages = obj.single;
  var x = 4; //for tests and creating new ID's
  var sub = 1; //for submission
  var err = 1; //for errors
  pages.forEach(function(page) {
    var test =
      "<div class='row'>" +
      "<div class='col s12 m12'>" +
      "<div class='card teal accent-1 hoverable' id='car'>" +
      "<div class='card-content  center-align'>" +
      "<span class='card-title'>" +
      "Question " +
      page.id +
      "</span>" +
      "<form action='#'>" +
      "<p>" +
      page.question +
      "</p>" +
      "<p><input name='group1' type='radio' id='test" +
      (x - 3) +
      "'/>" +
      "<label for='test" +
      (x - 3) +
      "'>" +
      page.option[0] +
      "</label></p>" +
      "<p><input name='group1' type='radio' id='test" +
      (x - 2) +
      "'/>" +
      "<label for='test" +
      (x - 2) +
      "'>" +
      page.option[1] +
      "</label></p>" +
      "<p><input name='group1' type='radio' id='test" +
      (x - 1) +
      "'/>" +
      "<label for='test" +
      (x - 1) +
      "'>" +
      page.option[2] +
      "</label></p>" +
      "<p><input name='group1' type='radio' id='test" +
      x +
      "'/>" +
      "<label for='test" +
      x +
      "'>" +
      page.option[3] +
      "</label></p>" +
      "</form>" +
      "<h6 id='error" +
      err +
      "'>Please select an option</h6>" +
      "</div>" +
      "<div class='card-action center'>" +
      "<button class='btn'  onclick='my(" +
      x +
      "," +
      sub +
      "," +
      err +
      ")' id='submit" +
      sub +
      "'>Submit</button>" +
      "</div>" +
      "</div>" +
      "</div>" +
      "</div>";
    $(".container").append(test);
    console.log(test);
    x += 4;
    sub++;
    err++;
  });
}
read();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: It totally worked.I thought the problem was in the region of Event binding on dynamically created elements but you totally save my day :)

Comment: I still think you're going about it the wrong way. Use classes and event delegation instead of all that inline Javascript.

Comment: Could you please show me how.I am still rather confused.

Comment: Sorry, completely rewriting your code is a little more work than I'm willing to do at 3am.

Comment: No problem ,You have really helped me a lot and it 12:30 pm here :)